# Logging minlevel to log file

Tags: c#, nlog

This seems like it would be an easy thing to do and would be a common desire, but I'm curious about a good way to do it. I would like to write the minlevel for a specific logger to its log file upon startup. I am routinely looking at logs and trying to remember how I left the log level for that application without having to dig up the NLog.config file. I would like a log entry that would look something like this:

> 2018-08-03 09:38:23.7975 | INFO | Starting with Log Level set to:
>   Debug

I can see that I should be able to access the LoggingConfiguration as such:

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration
```

But how do I access the rules and minlevel from that? Any other suggestions? If you can suggest some good NLog resources in addition to [the NLog Tutorial](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial), I would appreciate it.

Comment: Check if `logger.IsTraceEnabled` is true, if not, check if `IsDebugEnabled` is true, if not, check if `IsInfoEnabled`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the comments and answers. Severius5, your answer (deleted now?) gave me my answer.  This code does what I need:

```
        var rules = NLog.LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules;
        var rule = rules.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LoggerNamePattern == "hostLogger");
        NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("hostLogger").Info("Minimum Log Level: {0}", rule.Levels.Min());
```

It gave me this output in the log:

> 2018-08-03 14:26:11.7439 | INFO | Minimum Log Level: Debug

Comment: Your comments about the downvote should be comments on the question.  They aren't really part of your answer.

Comment: On a side note regarding the downvote, this is my first SO question and I would appreciate knowing how to improve my questions in the future. It's a bit of a daunting act to post a question here and given that the first response was a downvote, I'm not keen on asking again. (thank you for your comments, @Amy.)

Comment: Well, I meant on the question, but regardless your answer is much improved now, and for what it's worth, I have no idea why you were downvoted.  I wouldn't take it personally though.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
var logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger("hostLogger");
var minLogLevel = "Disabled";
if (logger.IsTraceEnabled)
    minLogLevel = "Trace";
else if (logger.IsDebugEnabled)
    minLogLevel = "Debug";
else if (logger.IsInfoEnabled)
    minLogLevel = "Info";
else if (logger.IsWarnEnabled)
    minLogLevel = "Warn";
else if (logger.IsErrorEnabled)
    minLogLevel = "Error";
else if (logger.IsFatalEnabled)
    minLogLevel = "Fatal";
logger.Info("Minimum Log Level: {0}", minLogLevel)
```